# Computers on the network randomly try to contact ISP DHCP not router DHCP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dhcp

I've been fighting with this issue for a few weeks, but one of my clients has Cox Communications as an ISP, with their standard modem, and a Netgear Nighthawk x6 router.

Originally the client had the modem/router combo from Cox, but this was switched out last week.

One strange issue that we're receiving is that computers seem to attempt to bypass the router DHCP server when connecting to the router, and instead attempt to communicate with the Cox server. This has lead me to have to assign static IPs, and hardcode the configuration of every computer in the building. This method works fine, with one exception. Several people have laptops that they need to use to commute to and from home with, so static mapping is not an option for them. Has anyone ever experienced anything like this?

Comment: Off the top of my head, the DHCP clients may be trying to contact the original DHCP server they had talked to previously to renew their leases.  However, they should revert to normal broadcast behavior if the renew is unsuccessful.

Comment: What's odd is that it's getting assigned a gateway of `192.168.1.200` and a DHCP server of the same IP. It's setting the DNS server to `192.168.63.1`. I tried setting the router to use `10.0.0.1` as the gateway, but this has done nothing the quell the issue.

Comment: I may have finally figured out what it is. It appears that specific IP is assigned to the client's security cameras, and it's causing issues on the network. Now to figure out how to bypass it.

Comment: Dup IPs makes more sense as far as causing disruptions on the network - cable uses CMTS, so if you have a modem on-site, the protocol used on the Cox side of that device is not something that your PCs will understand. The modem is what translates that signal into Ethernet for the router and PCs to use.

Comment: Configure the router to narrow the dhcp range, then set the ip for the camera outside the dhcp range you set.

Comment: The usual setup is modem -> router -> clients. DHCP uses a broadcast packet to communicate with the server so broadcast packets are not spread across subnet boundaries (we say that a subnet is its own broadcast domain). This means that something quite strange is happening or your network is misconfigured somehow.